# Submit form with AJAX and set input field to readonly

Tags: forms, jquery, readonly

I have a problem with submitting form with AJAX, print the response string under the form and set the input to readonly.

My code:

```
$('#save').click(
        function(){
            var form_data ={
            name: $('#name').val(),
            ajax:'1'
            };
            $.ajax({
                url:"page.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: form_data,
                success: function(data){
                         $('#form_message').html(data);
                }
            });
            $('#name').toggleClass('bgcolored');
            $('#save').addAttr('readonly');
            $('#save').toggleClass("invisible");        
            return false;
        }
```

If I delete the row `$('#save').addAttr('readonly');` the script works: it send values, catch the response and print it into the div `form_message` and toggle the two classes on the inputbox `#name` and on the submit button `#save`.
If I put `$('#save').addAttr('readonly');` (there or in the success function) the pages reloads and the message is lost.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$('#save').attr('readonly','true');
```

and deleting

```
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works!

```
$('#name').attr('readonly','true');
```

make it readoly without reloading page!

P.S.
I made a mistake in the question, obviously the "readonly" tag had to be applyed to the #name inputbox and not to the submit button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These days with jQuery 1.6.1 or above it is recommended to use .prop()

```
$("#fieldName").prop("readonly", true);
```